# How save nil in database using radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, input, radio-button, field

I have radio button and I want use it for saving attendance information:
yes, no, maybe

Code in HAML:

```
= f.input :attendee, :as => :radio, :collection => { "Yes" => true, "No" => false, "Maybe" => nil }, :label => "Attendence:"
```

Field attendee in database is boolean type.
When I change my value from Yes/No to Maybe rails didnt save 'nil' in database. What I should do to save 'nil'

Comment: in migration have you set default value for attendee?, if yes then it will never save nil value otherwise it will

Comment: I set nil as default value for attendee

Comment: Can you add (in an edit to your question) the value of Params from submitting the form with "Maybe" ticked?  It will be in your log.

Comment: i think try with "Maybe" => ""

Comment: @chaitanyasaraf thank you, your answer works :) make answer because I can't upvote

Comment: cool, please accept it

Comment: @chaitanyasaraf can you upvote question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boolean is `true/false`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type), you can't have `nil` (`nil` is treated as false):

> In computer science, the Boolean data type is a data type, having two values (usually denoted true and false). *[[If not true, false]]*

You'd be better with an [`enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
#app/models/model.rb
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum attendee: [:yes, :no, :maybe]
end
```

This is slightly more bloated than using a `boolean`, but retains [data integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_integrity) (you'll have to hack the Rails boolean to get it to recognize `nil` as `maybe`). `Enum` columns are `integers`, each `enum` being represented by a number...

> `yes = 0`
>
> `no  = 1`
>
> `maybe = 2`

This way, you'd be able to do the following:

```
= f.input :attendee, as: :radio, collection: Model.attendees, :label => "Attendence:"
```

Comment: For better or for worse, if you add a column of type boolean, by default null values are often accepted.

Comment: I had to set the default explicitly because Rails was acting weird with null values. I've forgotten the specifics

Answer (score 2):

If boolean value is set default to true or false then it wont accepts null value, otherwise you can pass blank value to boolean field as suggested below.

```
= f.input :attendee, :as => :radio, :collection => { "Yes" => true, "No" => false, "Maybe" => "" }, :label => "Attendence:"
```

Comment: Values can be potentially changed on client so you don't want to base your domain logic on client values. Since op mentioned that he already set the default value to nil - just accept params and filter out any values that are not true or false.


```
def attendee_params
  params.permit(attendence: ["1", "2"])
   #don't remember strong param api by heart so you would have to check it
end
```